# R: How to use intervals as input data for histograms?

Tags: r

I would like to import the data into R as intervals, then I would like to count all the numbers falling within these intervals and draw a histogram from this counts.

Example:

```
start end freq
1 8 3
5 10 2
7 11 5
.
.
.
```

Result:

```
number freq
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 3
5 5
6 5
7 10
8 10
9 7
10 7
11 5
```

Some suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not sure I see how the example data maps to the result data.

Comment: I would like to count the occurence of each number across all of the intervals (which also have frequency values attached): in the above example e.g. number 6 occurs in first and second interval and because 1st interval has frequency of 3 and the second frequency of 2, its count is 5 (3+2).

Comment: What you're asking for is a **bar chart**, not a **histogram**.  Try using `barplot` .

Comment: Dear Carl, thank you. However, my problem is not here. The question is how to manipulate interval data to count the elements in all intervals and then use whatever to visualize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `df`, you can create a data set that has each number in the range repeated by `freq`.  Once you have that it's trivial to use the summarizing functions in R.  This is a little roundabout, but a lot easier than explicitly computing the sum of the overlaps (though that isn't that hard either).

```
dat <- unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) rep(x[[1]]:x[[2]], x[[3]])))
hist(dat, breaks=0:max(df$end))
```

[image]

You can also do `table(dat)`

```
 dat
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
 3  3  3  3  5  5 10 10  7  7  5
```

Comment: Doggone it!  I was going to say that :-)